# How can I get root access after I installed Ubuntu on my PC?

Tags: command-line

How can I get root access after I installed Ubuntu on my PC? The system keeps telling me that I have to be root for execution some of the commands.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to prefix such commands with `sudo`.  By default the userid you created during the installation will be able to use `sudo`.   When you use `sudo` you will be prompted for the password of the userid you are running the command from (not the root password).  You can enable additional users by adding them to the `admin` group or adding them to `/etc/sudoers`.  On Ubuntu this can be done by adding the appropriate configuration lines to a file in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory.  These files need to be owned by root, and should no be accessible to others.

The command `visudo` can be used to safely edit `sudoers` files.  By default it will use `vi` as the editor but it will use another editor if the `EDITOR` environment variable has been set to the desired command and exported.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sudo` in front of the commands that are asking to be run a root.

`sudo` basically tells Ubuntu to run the command as the root user

You will be asked for your password

An alternative is running the `sudo -i` command and this will run all commands entered as root for as long as that terminal session remains open or `exit` is typed

EDIT: Be carefully with the `sudo` command as you can do seriously damage to Ubuntu, as I have found out many times myself.